# Writing unicode characters to file in Python

Tags: python, unicode

Take the following sample data (whole list can be found [here](https://github.com/minimaxir/big-list-of-naughty-strings/blob/master/blns.txt)):

```
Ω≈ç√∫˜µ≤≥÷
åß∂ƒ©˙∆˚¬…æ
œ∑´®†¥¨ˆøπ“‘
¡™£¢∞§¶•ªº–≠
¸˛Ç◊ı˜Â¯˘¿
ÅÍÎÏ˝ÓÔÒÚÆ☃
Œ„´‰ˇÁ¨ˆØ∏”’
ヽ༼ຈل͜ຈ༽ﾉ ヽ༼ຈل͜ຈ༽ﾉ 
(｡◕ ∀ ◕｡)
｀ｨ(´∀｀∩
_   _ﾛ(,_,*)
・(￣∀￣)・:*:
```

I have been outputting the data from the aformentioned dump of string to a separate HTML files (there is no need to get into detail as this is irrelevant to the question) like so:

```
for value in tags['tags']:
    for line in data:
        with open('./output/fuzzml' + str(file_count), 'w') as output:
            parsed_string = value.replace('[[VAR]]', u''.join(line.rstrip()))
            output.write(parsed_string)
            file_count += 1
```

Which works nicely for a relatively small portion of the data dump until it comes across some of the tricky symbols like the ones above. I have modified line 5 (`u''.join(line.rstrip())`) multiple times in hopes of writing in a way that will output anything correctly however it will always get stuck at some point and will raise an `UnicodeDecodeError` exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "generate-html.py", line 37, in <module>
  main()
File "generate-html.py", line 34, in main
  generate_html(tag_file, data_file)
File "generate-html.py", line 18, in generate_html
  parsed_string = value.replace('[[VAR]]', u''.join(line.rstrip()))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

---

The `tags` are extracted from a JSON file with the following sample set:

```
"tags": [
          "<img src=\"[[VAR]]\">",
          "<a href=\"[[VAR]]\"><img src=\"[[VAR]]\">",
          "<script>[[VAR]]</script>",
          "<[[VAR]]>Hello World<[[VAR]]>"
   ]
```

`data` is just the raw strings from the above link/sample data.

Comment: What type is `value` here? Is it a bytestring perhaps?

Comment: Just comes from a JSON file, I'll append that in the question in a moment.

Comment: And what type are the objects in `data`? Is each line a `unicode` object or a `str` bytestring?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - ought to be `str` bytestring but I will double-check and let you know.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using `'u''.join()` on a string object here. That it just keeping Python busy for no positive effect whatsoever. `''.join()` will convert the string to a list of individual characters, then rejoin those again to one string. But by using `u''`, you also force an implicit conversion to a `unicode` string.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have changed this to `unicode(line.rstrip())` instead as the other way was more of a workaround that I thought would work. I'm receiving the same exception so I presume this hasn't changed anything really. I feel I'm approaching this incorrectly

Comment: `unicode(bytestring)` decodes the value using the standard codec, ASCII. What codec was used for those strings, you need to *explicitly* state the correct codec.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - that's what I thought, but from the log I can see that it is only exporting the regular `ascii` characters but will immediately raise the exception once it gets to a single unicode character

Comment: Yes, because decoding ASCII bytes with the ASCII codec is perfectly legal. But you don't have ASCII only. You have UTF-8 (of which ASCII is a subset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At issue is your use of `u''.join()` here:

```
u''.join(line.rstrip())
```

This is pretty useless; it is breaking up the string into individual characters, then rejoining those back into a `unicode` string again. You were probably aiming for the side-effect of this: implicit conversion to a `unicode` string.

You could get the same effect with:

```
unicode(line.rstrip())
```

which will fail with the exact same error, because neither version tells Python what codec was used for the bytestring to encode your characters.

Decode your lines *explicitly*; the file you linked to is encoded to UTF-8:

```
unicode(line.rstrip(), 'utf-8')
```

or

```
line.rstrip().decode('utf-8')
```

Next problem is that your `parsed_string` object is now a Unicode object too, so you'll need to encode that again when writing to a file:

```
output.write(parsed_string.encode('utf8'))
```

or use the [`io.open()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) to open a file object that encodes Unicode strings for you as you write.

You may want to read:

- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

before continuing to fully understand how Python and Unicode work together.

Comment: So after importing the `data` file into notepad++ it seems it should be `UTF-8 w/o BOM` and `unicode(line.rstrip(), 'utf-8')` works for say `╬®Ôëê├ºÔêÜÔê½╦£┬ÁÔëñÔëÑ├À` but still chokes on the rest further down the file.

Comment: @Juxhin: it decodes your file just fine. You probably have other problems elsewhere.

Comment: Actually it seems that notepad++ isn't decoding all the file properly, sublime actually displays all of the characters just fine. I'll just read a bit more about it.

Comment: You summed it up nicely in the end. `output.write(parsed_string.encode('utf8'))` was required as we now have a Unicode object. Works great. Thanks Martijn.